# How do I replace the number buttons on a keyless deadbolt?

Tags: deadbolt

My keyless deadbolt works great, however the numbers are worn off the buttons.  Can the buttons be replaced without buying a new lock?

Comment: Picture would be helpful.

Comment: You do know that there are multiple brands and styles. The answer probably depends on these.

Comment: You might want to ask manufacturer how much just the buttons would cost.  That might be the deciding factor; not "can they be replaced" but "how much would it cost to do so"...if the keys are avail. solo.

Comment: Can you use a Sharpie to re-write the numbers?